# Impact on GCP Cloud functions during label change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

What is the impact for `CLoud functions`  during deployment ? Does the `function` become unavailable during deployment or any `trigger` during this deployment time will fail ?

I can deploy using `GCP Console` or by using below `gcloud` command

```
gcloud functions deploy HelloWorld --source golang-samples-master/functions/codelabs/gopher --update-labels env=dev,name=automate --trigger-http --runtime go111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud function still available during the deployment of a new version, it will continue accepting/processing request until the new deployment is completed successfully

Comment: What if the deployment fails , will it continue to serve from Old version ?

Comment: if the deployment of a new version fails, the previous working version will continue working. there will be a warning icon next to the function name indicating "Function is active, but the last deploy failed"

Comment: Thanks so much... You clarified a lot